# SQL Server query with join from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables:

`cicmpy` with columns:

```
ID  ItemCode    Description SecurityLevel   Type    debcode
```

and table `AAA2` with column

```
KLIENCIID
```

I need `select * from cicmpy` with data (ID) from KLIID.

I tried this select statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.cicmpy 
WHERE debcode IN (SELECT KLIENCIID FROM AAA2)
```

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.AAA2
```

| KLIENCIID |
| --- |
| 300000 |
| 300001 |
| 300002 |

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.cicmpy 
WHERE dbo.cicmpy.debcode = 300000;
```

| ID | ItemCode | debcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | ED8D7F34-88A6-439B-85FC-AC9B1461E547 | 300000 |

Comment: `select * from dbo.AAA2 WHERE dbo.AAA2.KLIENCIID = 300000;`  ← What does that output?

Comment: KLIENCIID|
---------+
300000   |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema and insert statements:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AAA2 (KLIENCIID varchar(10));

INSERT INTO dbo.AAA2 VALUES(300000);
INSERT INTO dbo.AAA2 VALUES(300001);
INSERT INTO dbo.AAA2 VALUES(300002);
 
CREATE TABLE dbo.cicmpy 
(
     ID int, 
     ItemCode varchar(200), 
     debcode varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.cicmpy 
VALUES (46, 'ED8D7F34-88A6-439B-85FC-AC9B1461E547', 300000);
```

Select query:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM dbo.cicmpy c 
INNER JOIN AAA2 a ON LTRIM(RTRIM(c.debcode)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(a.KLIENCIID))
```

Output:

| ID | ItemCode | debcode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 46 | ED8D7F34-88A6-439B-85FC-AC9B1461E547 | 300000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1c55be7a0f9c4aa9bd43a937b5ead579)*

Comment: 0 rows, no data output.

Comment: Please share some data from both your tables. Please also mention whether your query  (SELECT * FROM dbo.cicmpy WHERE debcode IN (SELECT KLIENCIID FROM AAA2)) is returning rows.

Comment: I add to first question.

Comment: @masterzst It's returning rows I have shared db-fiddle link. Please mention the data type of columns debcode and KLIENCIID.

Comment: varchar in two tables

Comment: @masterzst I have revised my answer for varchar data type.

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Maybe the problem is with the SQL version, this is the 2005 version

Comment: Instead of trim() you need to use ltrim(rtrim()). I have again revised my answer.